# How to generate HTML from .vue component

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2, server-side-rendering, vue-loader

I want to create simple static site generator that use VueJS.

I have simple vue component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-child
      v-for="child in children"
      :title="'Child ' + child.id"
      :key="child.id"
    >
      {{ child.name }}
    </v-child>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import children from './children';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      children
    };
  }
}
</script>
```

and want to implement function that generates HTML from it:

```
describe('generateHTML', () => {
  it('generates HTML from vue component', async () => {
    expect(await generateHTML(__dirname + '/fixtures/v-parent.vue'))
      .to.equal('<div><div class="child"><div>Child 1</div><div>First</div></div><div class="child"><div>Child 2</div><div>Second</div></div></div>')
  });
});
```

Do you have some idea / tips how can I do it ?

Here is repo that reproduces my issue:
[lusarz/vue-questions](https://github.com/lusarz/vue-questions)

Just run:

```
npm install
npm run test
```

I did some initial tries, but now it works like:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can use `mount` function from [@vue/test-utils](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/#mount)

```js
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import Foo from './Foo.vue'

describe('Foo Component', () => {
  it('check rendered component html', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(Foo)
    expect(wrapper.html()).toBe("<--- Your Html --->")
  })
})
```